# How to display data from one table and then insert that data to another table in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to fetch data from  table whose mem_count is equal to 2 and then insert that data to another table after last unique_id.

Here is my code :

```
$mem_count2=mysql_query("SELECT mem_count,mem_id FROM member_status WHERE mem_count = 2 order by mem_id ASC");

if(mysql_num_rows($mem_count2 )==0){

      die(mysql_error()); 
     }
 else{

          $start_value=00;
  // $start_value dynamically comes from other table which i am not mentioning here
       // $start_value can starts from any number For Eg. 2, 5.

        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($mem_count2)) {

       $uniq_code="PHR-" . str_pad((int) $start_value, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);


         //if mem_id already inserted then use IGNORE in INSERT i.e INSERT IGNORE

            $cql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO member_code (mem_id, temp_code,unique_code) values ('".$row['mem_id']."','".$row['mem_count']."','".$uniq_code."')";

          mysql_query($cql) or exit(mysql_error()); 

        $start_value++; 

       }
    }
```

It runs smoothly but sometimes i am getting this output:

```
+------------+-------------+
| mem_id     | unique_code |
+------------+-------------+
|  1         | PHR-01      |
+------------+-------------+
|  5         | PHR-02      |
+------------+-------------+
|  3         | PHR-04      |
+------------+-------------+
```

Some problem is surely in the INSERT IGNORE query!I have made mem_id as UNIQUE. Please rectify this as i am completely stuck over it !

Member_code structure

```
+------------+-------------+-----+
| mem_id     | unique_code | Id  |
+------------+-------------+-----+
|  1         | PHR-01      | 1   | 
+------------+-------------+-----+
|  5         | PHR-02      | 5   |
+------------+-------------+-----+
|  3         | PHR-04      | 3   |
+------------+-------------+-----+
```

Comment: Warning, mysql_* functions have been deprecated. Use PDO going forward.

Comment: I am aware of that but right now i want to use this only !

Comment: That's fine.  Just pointing it out for other visitors, so they know not to use your logic, which will break once the functions are removed from a future version of PHP.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because you are getting an error at some point at this line

`mysql_query($cql) or exit(mysql_error());`

and then your increment variable will be incremented for the next insert. You should test the insert and if doesn't get error you do the increment.

Comment: Sorry but i am not getting any error.The thing is i am getting non-serialize unique ids For Eg. PHR-O1 , PHR-03 , PHR-06 at some point !

Comment: I meant the data structure of the table, like `id integer primary key` etc.

Comment: okey- Id int primary key Auto_increment, mem_id int unique key , unique_code varchar(100)

Comment: Hummm... So I would print each insert statment and try to run on the database to see what happens `echo $cql;` inside the `while` It would give you some hint. If I would guess is that some of the `$row['mem_id']` already exists on the member_code table which is why the `IGNORE` statment is ignoring it because it is the primary key of the table. Can you check thoose options?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a variable called `$mem_count2` throughout your code, when the results are stored in `$mem_count`.

Comment: yes you are right but that is not the main problem ! Problem is somewhat with in INSERT IGNORE or in while loop.